# Why is default required in importing JSON file in JS code

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous

I have a JSON data which I can get from this [API](https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/oojs/json/superheroes.json).
However when I copy the contents of this link into a local file and save it as JSON, and then import in in JS like:

```
import * as data from "./data.json" assert { type: "json" };

console.log(data)
```

I am getting a module in my console where the default parameter contains my JSON object.[image]

But when I do:

```
import * as data from "./data.json" assert { type: "json" };

console.log(data.default)
```

Then only I can view my JSON object like normal, i.e. what would the output have been if I did:

```js
async function populate() {

  const requestURL = 'https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/oojs/json/superheroes.json';
  const request = new Request(requestURL);

  const response = await fetch(request);
  const superHeroes = await response.json();
  console.log(superHeroes)
}

populate();
```

Why does this happen? And is there any better method of importing my JSON file so that I can access it in my code?

Comment: Because if I do so, and try to console.log the object I get the error: `Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/json". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`. A quick google search led me to use `assert { type: "json" }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because the `import * as` line imports    [an_entire_modules_contents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_an_entire_modules_contents) where cause the absence of an explicit `export default`  the *default* property coincides with the content of your json file. If you want the `data` variable contains your json file you can use instead:

```
import {default as data} from "./data.json";
console.log(data); //<-- it will print the content of your json file
```

Or the simple shorthand below:

```
import data from "./data.json";
```

Comment: Your answer worked, but partly. When I used `import {default as data} from "./data.json"`, I got the error: `Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/json". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.` Using `import { default as data } from "./data.json" assert{type: "json"};` made the program work. Why does this happen?

Comment: @ritwick__D This happens because your configuration project (probably electron from the message error) does not permit the loading of a json file as a module unless you expressly asserts that is a json file, but this is an issue related to the used framework.